# Reading PushButton status with pyserial

Tags: serial, button, python

I'm trying to read the status of a PushButton with python via pyserial.

In the loop function of Arduino Uno I have this:

```
void loop() {

if(digitalRead(BUTTON) == HIGH){
Serial.print("E\n");
while(1){}
}
```

So, if my pushbutton is pressed, it will send this message "E" via serial and then it will enter in an infinite loop so that nothing else happens.

But I want to detect this message in the python code. So this is my python code:

```
import serial
import time

try:
   arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
except:
   print "Failed to connect on /dev/ttyACM0"


try:
   print arduino.readline()

   while True:
      if arduino.readline() == 'E':
        print("Detected!\n")

except:
   print ("Failed to read!")
```

The first print before the infinite While is working: it is printing in the ubuntu terminal "Program Initiated", which is a message that I'm sending in the void Setup function of Arduino.

Then, it gets stucked in the line:

```
 if arduino.readline() == 'E':
```

I mean, I press several times my pushbutton, and nothing is happening.

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: Use arduino.read instead of arduino.readline

Comment: Isn't more secure to use readline() once I will end up my message with \n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you are sending (`"E\n"`) is not the same one you are checking for: `'E'`.

You could, for example, strip newlines from the string:

```
if arduino.readline().strip() == 'E':
```

Comment: You're right! I thought that as I was using .readline (which stops reading with \n) it wouldn't be necessary to put it on. Thanks, now it's working - without using that strip thing. What does it do exactly?

Comment: `strip()` removes newlines and whitespace from the start and end of strings. I'm slightly surprised that `readline()` works at all if you're not sending newlines but OK if it does. Please feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful.